# Representing HEX: 1D524 with utf-8 representation?

Tags: unicode

I have to represent a character given by the hexadecimal 1D524 in its utf-8 form (11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx).

I've already converted the hexadecimal chain to binary, which gives me: 1 1101 0101 0010 0100. But when I try to represent those in utf-8, I get **11110**111 **10**010101 **10**001001 **10**00xxxx. Assuming all bytes should have 8 bits, I'm missing 4 bits, so obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Help?

Comment: Well, in my class notes, it says that I have to encode as 4 units from 17 bits to 21 and I have 17.

Comment: Your question is similar to asking how to represent "1" as a 32-bit integer, and wondering "what to do with the other 31 bits", since 1 only requires 1 bit.

Comment: So I should just add 4 0s before 1 1101 0010 0100 and encode it as such? As 1110000 10011101 10010100 10100100?